# mthod level authrization is not working in spring security

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, spring-security

I found many similar questions but none have solved my problem. 
//spring security file
when i am using method level annotation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") it always print anonmousUser. I have a separate file for applicationContext.

Spring security method level @PreAuthorize ignored by spring security
enter image description here
My spring-security.xml code is following.
[Code screenshot][1]

```
//aspsecurity-servlet.xml
    <bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.asp.*" />
        <!-- Getting Database properties -->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
        <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />
        <mvc:resources location="/**" mapping="/css/**" />
        <mvc:resources location="/**" mapping="/js/**" />
        <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
        <!-- Resolves Views Selected For Rendering by @Controllers to *.jsp Resources in the /WEB-INF/ Folder -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teuci.png


//security.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans>

        <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
        <!-- spring security configuration -->
        <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/domain*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

            <!-- user-defined login form redirection -->
            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/domain/"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />

            <!-- logout url -->
            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />

            <!-- csrf disabled -->
            <csrf disabled="true" /> 
        </http>
        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select user_name, password, enabled from USERS where user_name = ?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="select u.user_name, ur.authority from USERS u, USERS_ROLES ur where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.user_name = ?" />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <!-- database configuration (database = MySql) -->
        <beans:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName"
                value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <beans:property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asp" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asp.model"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Transaction -->
        <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    </beans:beans>

//web.xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Airport support app</display-name>

    <!-- spring configuration - process the application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>aspsecurity</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>aspsecurity</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/aspsecurity-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- spring security configuration -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>

//Java 
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ModelAndView getAddDomain() {
}
```

Comment: where does it print anonymousUser? what has that got to do with the annotation?

Comment: Is an exception thrown? If so please post. Your xml looks fine so far. I guess that your database query is not working. Can you proove it does?

Comment: there is no exception. when go via login page it print correct role inside method like ROLE_ADMIN but PreAuthorize will not work. and with without login method return result without authentication,. i have already put PreAuthrize annotation. but it is not working. please help me.